Fling's interaction with Rekindling Phoenix
So I've tried this twice now.
I cast Heartfire targeting an enemy creature, sacrificing a Gutterbones as part of the cost; the Gutter then ends up exiled for some reason.
EDIT
Turns out I was targeting Misery's Shadow, which caused the exile.

I think we'd need to see a screenshot of the board state to actually address this. Nothing in the card Fling or Rekindling Phoenix mentions the exile zone at all, so the most likely explanation is that some other card caused this.

The Phoenix had a finality counter on it, and/or your opponent had Gisa, Glorious Resurrector or similar creature on board that causes creatures to be exiled instead of dying.

@Hackworth or similar enchantment (Leyline of the Void) or artifact (don't know one off the top of my head)

@PhilipKendall Stone of Erech, theres also rest in peace, misery's shadow, Valentin, Nemata, Liesa, even brittle blast since its arena

"but thought I'd ask" - what is the question?

What did Heartfire target? I assume you cast it on your turn two to kill their turn one or turn two play, but we can't see whatever card it is, because it's in their graveyard under the March Toward Perfection.

Sorry I forgot to screenshot her graveyard, and I don't remember what it was, but I'm sure I can reproduce it. Seems to be related to being a private match, because I couldn't reproduce it using the tutorial wisp thing.

@DarkNeuron Could the creature you targeted have been any of these?

Yes, now I'm embarrassed. It was the shade.

No need to reopen this then. Thanks @Hackworth

@DarkNeuron you're welcome and no worries, happens to everyone.

@Hackworth surely it doesn't matter that one of those creatures was targeted, even, just that the opponent controlled one?

@KarlKnechtel it doesn't matter that it was what was targeted, but because it was targeted by a spell that removed it it hid the creature when looking at the board state which is what caused the confusion.

There was probably some other effect involved which caused the exile. There's a lot of cards that exile things that would die or otherwise go to the graveyard. Cards like Rest in Peace and Leyline of the Void see play in some metas Stone of Erech is in sideboads in others, Kumano Faces Kakkazan is in a lot of red aggro decks, though your phoenix would have to take damage for it to trigger.
This probably isn't a bug, even happening multiple times the cards that exile are common and used enough, you probably just didn't notice the effects already in play that were going to make the card exile, without seeing the board state there's no way to be sure.

I thought the same, and I checked the entire field every time. I played against a friend, and I know their deck pretty well. They have no such exile effect, nor do I.

If it happens again, please grab a screenshot of the board at the time and add it to this question - it can then be reopened.

It was Misery's Shadow

@DarkNeuron makes sense, you may want to edit your edit to the question about that then?

Done @Andrew. Removed excess ramblings.
